# Update to table joined on composite key

Tags: mysql, join, composite-key

I am trying to update rows in a data table that intersect rows in a smaller index table. The two tables are joined on the composite PK of the data table, and explain-select using the same criteria shows that the index is being used properly, and the correct unique rows are fetched - but I'm still having issues with the update.

The update on the joined tables works fine when there's only 1 row in the temp table, but when I have more rows, I get [MySql Error 1175](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_update_without_key_in_safe_mode), and none of the WHERE conditions I specify are recognized.

I'm aware that I can just switch off safe mode with SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0, but can anyone tell me what I'm not understanding here?  Why is my WHERE condition not accepted, and why does it even need a where when I'm doing a NATURAL JOIN - and why does this work with only one row in the right-hand-side table (MyTempTable)?

**The Code**

Below is vastly simplified, but structurally identical create table & updates representing my problem.

```
-- The Data Table.
Create Table MyDataTable
(
    KeyPartOne int not null,
    KeyPartTwo varchar(64) not null,
    KeyPartThree int not null,
    RelevantData varchar(200) null,
    Primary key (KeyPartOne, KeyPartTwo, KeyPartThree)
) Engine=InnoDB;

-- The 'Temp' table.
Create Table MyTempTable
(
    KeyPartOne int not null,
    KeyPartTwo varchar(64) not null,
    KeyPartThree int not null,
    Primary key (KeyPartOne, KeyPartTwo, KeyPartThree)
)Engine=Memory;

-- The Update Query (works fine with only 1 row in Temp table)
update MyDataTable natural join MyTempTable 
set RelevantData = 'Something Meaningful';

-- Specifying 'where' - roduces same effect as the other update query
update MyDataTable mdt join MyTempTable mtt
on mdt.KeyPartOne = mtt.KeyPartOne
and mdt.KeyPartTwo = mtt.KeyPartTwo
and mdt.KeyPartThree = mtt.KeyPartThree
set RelevantData = 'Something Meaningful'
where mdt.KeyPartOne = mtt.KeyPartOne
and mdt.KeyPartTwo = mtt.KeyPartTwo
and mdt.KeyPartThree = mtt.KeyPartThree;
```

P.S. Both of the above update statements work as expected when the temp table contains only one row, but give me the error when there's more than one row.  I'm seriously curious about why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the MySql forum, the update queries are valid, and the fact that they don't work in Workbench with safe-update mode turned on does not indicate that there's anything wrong with the index.  It's just a quirk of Workbench's "don't-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot" mode. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your first `UPDATE` query, you use `NATURAL JOIN`, which is the same as `NATURAL LEFT JOIN`.

In your second `UPDATE` query, you use `JOIN`, which is the same as `INNER JOIN`.

A `LEFT JOIN` is not the same as an `INNER JOIN`, and a `NATURAL JOIN` is not the same as a `JOIN`.

Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you are trying to update all rows in MyDataTable where a corresponding entry exists in MyTempTable, this query should do the trick:

```
UPDATE
    myDataTable mdt
    INNER JOIN MyTempTable mtt ON
        mdt.KeyPartOne = mtt.KeyPartOne
        AND mdt.KeyPartTwo = mtt.KeyPartTwo
        AND mdt.KeyPartThree = mtt.KeyPartThree
SET
    mdt.RelevantData = 'Something Meaningful'
```

If that's not what you're trying to do, please clarify and I will update my answer.

Comment: Could you cite a source for "NATURAL JOIN, which is the same as NATURAL LEFT JOIN"?  According to [the man page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) - scroll down to 'join processing changes' - a natural join is the same as equivi-join with 'USING', which is interpreted as an inner join on the specified fields.  Additionally, I also tried what you suggest - note that this is the second query I posted, under "-- Specifying 'where'".  It still complained about missing key in where, so I provided that - but it doesn't seem to be recognized as a valid key.

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi: Perhaps I'm mistaken. I looked at the same page, where it says "The NATURAL [LEFT] JOIN of two tables ..." and interpreted that as meaning that `NATURAL JOIN` is the same as `NATURAL LEFT JOIN`, but after taking another look, I realize that may not be right. Also, I just realized that I hadn't understood your question fully, and that the problem is that MySQL is throwing the error because you are in safe update mode. Sorry, but I don't have any experience with the quirks of safe update mode.

Comment: Ty for trying anyway!  Just wondering what this says about the way MySql uses composite indexes.  Hope someone can explain this!

Comment: What if you were to trick it by doing something like `WHERE mdt.KeyPartOne LIKE '%'`...perhaps that would work?